# Handling many times the same operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm looking for a way to "divide" multiple operations that needs to be done so as to gain efficiency.

Let me put an example to explain my need.

Say that I have this object:

```
public class CardInfo
{
    public int mCardID { get; set; }

    public string mCardName { get; set; }

    public int? mCardNumber { get; set; }

    public string mCardColor { get; set; }

    (...)
}
```

Each objects may be linked to a price list object:

```
public class PriceListInfo
{
    public int mPriceListId { get; set; }

    public int mPriceProviderID { get; set; }

    public PriceProviderInfo mPriceListProvider { get; set; }

    public int mCardID { get; set; }

    public CardInfo mCard { get; set; }

    public decimal? mPriceLow { get; set; }

    public decimal? mPriceMid { get; set; }

    public decimal? mPriceHigh { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a process which task is to actually get a list of cards and build the price list of each cards, like this:

```
List<CardInfo> listCards = mCardManager.ListCardsForCardSet(_cardSetID);

foreach(var card in listCards)
{
    List<PriceListInfo> listPrices = mPriceManager.ListPricesForCar(card);
}
```

Something quite simple, however if the list of cards contains more than 500 items, it will take a while. I am wondering (and since I don't know much about Asp.Net, it is why I am asking the question) if there's a way to divide the list by an [X] number and then launch many times the `List<PriceListInfo> listPrices = mPriceManager.ListPricesForCar(card);` line? Or is there a way to make these operation asynchronously? (please pardon my ignorance, thank you.) Can anybody explain how could I proceed, and if you could provide an example, I'd be more than happy.

Comment: Have you looked into using `Parallel.Foreach`?  Check out this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720.aspx

Comment: Nope, I did not know this existed. If I understand well, this will split the operation in many and do the same thing that a `forEach` loop would do, much like what I'm looking for?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  The `Parallel` extensions use an algorithm to figure out the appropriate number of threads (mainly based on the number of physical/logical cores the machine that's running the code has) and will partition the data based on that value and run them in parallel.

Comment: Ok. Very interesting. I will need to try this out. Thank you! :)